# validating array of structs using goplayground validator library

Tags: validation, go, go-playground

How can I validate a slice of structs using validator framework?

For example, in the following type definitions, I want to validate each element in the field `Puppies`.

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string `json:"fname" validate:"alpha"`
    LastName  string `json:"lname" validate:"alpha"`
    Email     string `json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
    Puppies   []*Dog `json:"puppies"`
    // Puppy *Dog
}

type Dog struct {
    PuppyName string `json:"puppyname" validate:"alpha"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9-1Ih76hD7j is not working with array of dogs.

https://play.golang.org/p/PGQT3jaFVuS is working - with only one dog.

I want to validate the slice of structs, can we do it using goplayground validator framework?

Answer (score 6):

Use `dive` tag to perform validations on iterable structures:

```golang
Puppies   []*Dog `json:"puppies" validate:"dive"`
```

Refer to https://godoc.org/github.com/go-playground/validator#hdr-Dive

Comment: I tried with dive tag. It is working. ok so for slice, array, map I need to use dive tag. Thank you so much @lblisto